# How to calculate the surface heating of the ball thrown in different fluid mediums like air and water?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, friction, projectile

Let's say a ball is thrown at a certain velocity, then it follows a projectile motion and falls on the surface. Now, during this entire flight how can we calculate the temperature rise that happens in the surface of the ball due to the friction of the fluid medium? Assuming fluid is either air or water.

Comment: Use energy equations. Even then, there will be heating of the medium. You could assume a proportion to the ball, but if course, state your assumptions.

Comment: I don't think you can calculate since most of the energy lost goes in heating th surrounding air (or water), so your ball will get almost no heat.